# Form Submitting Before JQuery Dialog Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a form submit function in js like so:

```
$('#announcement_form').submit(function (event) {
        if ($("input[name=urgency]:checked").attr('value') != "not") {
            $("input[name=urgency_option][value='no']").prop("checked",true);

            $("#dialog").dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 820,
                height: 205,
                resizable: false,
                close: function() {
                    if ($("input[name='urgency_option']:checked").attr("value") == "yes") {
                        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        $("input[name=urgency][value='not']").prop("checked",true);
                        $("input[name='urgent[]']").each(function(index) {
                            $(this).prop("disabled", true);
                        });
                        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }).prev(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css({"background":"#00295B", "color":"white", "font-weight":"normal"});
            $("#dialog").dialog("moveToTop");
        }
    });
```

For some reason my form submits before even allowing the user to make a dialog selection. The dialog pops up for a split second and then the form submits. However, it is supposed to wait until it returns true or false.

Can anybody help?

Note: I must keep using a form (no onclick button).

Comment: Are you doing anything to stop the form from being submitted?

Comment: I am returning false if the "no" option was selected. Which theoretically should stop the form from submitting.

Comment: You're only doing that within the dialog. You need to stop the form from being submitted first. Opening a jQuery modal dialog doesn't block the browser from submitting the form automatically -- you have to do it.

Comment: I understand that. That is my question. I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: You can move the `return false` outside of the dialog code or use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the submission. Then instead of `return true`, submit the form using the `.submit()` function.